# Derivation of session keys from master_secrets during session resumption

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, openssl

As far as i understand,

```
Master_key = PRF("pre_master_key", client.random, server.random)
```

Session keys and other keys derived from Master_key, Client.Random and Server.Random.

After session resumption, Master_key will be same as i know.

Will session keys and other key again derived or it will take previous derived ?

Answer (score 1):

I think key_block generation does not care about whether we are doing resumption or not and is the same in all cases:

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246 :

```
      master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret",
                          ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random)
                          [0..47];
```

(snip)

```
   To generate the key material, compute

      key_block = PRF(SecurityParameters.master_secret,
                      "key expansion",
                      SecurityParameters.server_random +
                      SecurityParameters.client_random);

   until enough output has been generated.  Then, the key_block is
   partitioned as follows:

      client_write_MAC_key[SecurityParameters.mac_key_length]
      server_write_MAC_key[SecurityParameters.mac_key_length]
      client_write_key[SecurityParameters.enc_key_length]
      server_write_key[SecurityParameters.enc_key_length]
      client_write_IV[SecurityParameters.fixed_iv_length]
      server_write_IV[SecurityParameters.fixed_iv_length]
```

Comment: But, Key_block uses **server_random** and **client_random**.. right ? So, during session resumption, **client_random** and **server_random** will changed because Client Hello and Server Hello message are exchange between server and client

So, my question is, during the resumption Master key is same. but server_random and client_random are changed so key_block is again calculated ?

Comment: @DevangKubavat: I have never implemented this, so my understanding is only from reading the documentation. But if `master_secret` is unchanged, then don't `server_random` and `client_random` HAVE to be the unchanged as well? (Since they are part of the building blocks for "master_secret".)

Comment: Okay... @StackzOfZtuff. It's part of master_secret. but my doubt is that i read from OpenSSL wiki: session resumption is useful to re-issue the session ticket so i think like that... may be master_secret will be same but key_block again re-calculated based on new client_random and server_random.

Comment: @DevangKubavat: but `master_secret` is the result of cryptographic mixing of the `server_random` and `client_random` and more stuff. If even one bit of the input to that cryptographic mixing changes, then the output changes completely.